# style first and last CSS data attribute with border

Tags: css, sass

I have the following HTML markup which cannot be changed (please don't ask why..).

I want to add a border-top and border-bottom to the first and last div's within each collection of divs.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="product" data-productindex="0"></div>
  <div class="product" data-productindex="0"></div>
  <div class="product" data-productindex="0"></div>
  <div class="product" data-productindex="0"></div>
  <div class="product" data-productindex="0"></div>

  <div class="product" data-productindex="1"></div>
  <div class="product" data-productindex="1"></div>
  <div class="product" data-productindex="1"></div>
  <div class="product" data-productindex="1"></div>
  <div class="product" data-productindex="1"></div>
</div>
```

I have tried adding `last-of-type` & `first-of-type` like

```
[data-productindex='0']:first-of-type { border-top: 1px solid black` }
```

and

```
[data-productindex='0']:last-of-type { border-bottom: 1px solid black` }
```

And then repeat that for index 1 but no luck. I'm using SASS